# ModelForm in Django not showing

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to display a basic form in django but does not render the form once I run the server, I would appreciate if you could help me with these, here my code.

**models.py**

```
STATUS_OPTIONS =(
    ('OP', 'OPEN'),
    ('CL', 'CLOSED')
)

class Employee(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_OPTIONS)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Employee

class EmployeeForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = "__all__"
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.create_employee),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import EmployeeForm

# Create your views here.

def create_employee(request):
    form = EmployeeForm()
    return render(request, 'employee/create_employee.html', {'form':form})
```

**create_employee.html**

```
<h1>Formu</h1>
<form action="" method='POST'>
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I run the program the only thing rendered is the  tag, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create forms out of models you need to use `ModelForm` not `Form`. Otherwise you end up with a regular form without any field.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Employee

class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    #...
```

More about `ModelForm` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem :D!